# Why does this htaccess end in a redirection loop?

Tags: apache, .htaccess, redirect

I got the following htaccess that ends up in a redirection loop:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/int(.*)$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /int [R,L]

RewriteRule . index.php [L]
```

I added the first rule to redirect root requests to a specific sub folder.
The second rule comes from WordPress (among others)

I dont see why this should end in a redirection loop.
Does the second rewrite trigger another request so that the htaccess is checked again? Thant would explain the loop.

Thank you

Answer (score 2):

Each of your rewrites creates a new request which is reprocessed through the .htaccess.
You're rewriting anything doesn't start with `/int(.*)` to `/int`.  However, anything that starts with `/int` skips the first rewrite condition and gets rewritten to `index.php`.  Then `index.php` gets rewriten to `/int` because it doesn't start with `/int(.*)`.  Then `/int` gets rewritten to `index.php`... and on ...and on...

BTW: You could prevent the endless loop by  adding a second rewrite condition to not trigger your first rewrite rule to when the `REQUEST_URI` is `/index.php`

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/index.php$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/int(.*)$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /int [R,L]
```

If forget if you need the leading forward slash in the first rewite condition... try it both ways.

Answer (score 0):

You are telling any page that isn't in the `/int` folder is to be redirected `/int` folder, but the next line you are saying that all pages are to get redirected to the `index.php` page.
So the first rule says:

`http:example.com/about.php` will get redirected to -> `http:example.com/int`.
But  the second rule then says

`http:example.com/int` is to get redirected -> to `http:example.com/index.php`
then the first rule kicks back in and goes round and round again

Comment: I think I am telling it to be "handled" by the index.php page, not redirected. I did not know the the htaccess will get parsed after the rewrite

Comment: What do you mean `handled by the index.php` page?

Comment: That the client does not get redirected, just a rewrite